# How to mock a user defined function in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have received `.xlsb` file that references third party add in that I do not have. Spreadsheet uses a function defined in that add in some cells of the sheet and those cellls have `#NAME?` errors.

I have defined function with the same name and parameters in VBA.
The `#NAME?` errors still persist and it only works if I "touch" the cell. What I mean by that, I copy and paste the same formula.

Is there a more elegant way to replace (mock) a non existing function?

Answer (score 2):

To bypass the #NAME? error, find and replace all of the formulas containing the UDF name with the same UDF name.

```
dim myudf as string, w as long
myudf = "=MyUdf("
for w=1 to worksheets.count
    worksheets(w).cells.replace(what:=ucase(myudf), replacement:=lcase(myudf), _
                                matchcase:=false, lookat:=xlPart
next w
```

Comment: This essentially automates the "touching" bit. I'll have to propose this as a solution to quite a few people, do you have any references confirming that this is a correct way of doing things?

Answer (score 0):

Does the workbook have manual calculation turned on? If so, try switching to automatic (Tools>Options>Calculation). That may force it to recalculate instead of "touching" each cell.